# Are Azure Active Directory's TenantID and ClientID considered secrets?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

For testing purposes I've created an ASP.NET Core MVC app in VS2019 and added authentication "Cloud - Single organization".
As part of the creation process, VS registered an app in my subscription's Azure AD and allowed me to login with the users stored in there.

I then created another app registration in a different subscription and changed the MVC app's 'app settings.json' to contain the other subscription's app credentials:

- Domain
- TenantId
- ClientId

And now I could login with users stored in the other subscription's directory.

My question is: if I push my MVC app to a public git repo, should I consider the above credentials secrets and remove them before committing?

There's no real danger in my opinion but on the other hand it feels wrong to expose them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The both values (`tenant_id` and `client_id`) are not considered a secret. They are public. Once you publish your application publicly (and not just on intranet), everyone will be able to get both these values - they are both used in the OIDC redirect to authorization endpoint.

However I might consider hiding them anyway in the web.config / settings.json file - a general best practice for managing application settings. A nice opportunity to try [Azure Application Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/overview) service ;)